# Spark Mongo DB connector - No Class Def Found

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark

I am facing and issue when trying to read data form Mongo DB.

I have Spark 1.6.3 which has Scala 2.10.5

I am using the Mongo DB Connector Version 1.1 and package 2.10

Following is the dependencies i had used in my Mavan

```
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId> 
<artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.10</artifactId> 
<version>1.1.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

Getting error like

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/spark/rdd/api/java/JavaMongoRDD
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:175)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:708)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.spark.rdd.api.java.JavaMongoRDD
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

But was able to find the class existing in the reference

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is there any classnotfound exception ?

Comment: @QuickSilver :  Yes the below , 
`
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/spark/rdd/api/java/JavaMongoRDD
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.spark.rdd.api.java.JavaMongoRDD
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
`

Comment: @QuickSilver - I have added a comment , also added in the Post.

Answer (score 1):

Add mongo-spark-connector_2.10's jar to your run time class path

It can be done it followting ways,

- Add mongo-spark-connector jar to Spark lib folder
- `spark-submit` with `--jars=/path/mongo-spark-connector.jar`
- `spark.driver.extraClassPath` or it's alias `--driver-class-path` to set extra classpaths on the node running the driver.
- `spark.executor.extraClassPath` to set extra class path on the Worker nodes.

If you add Driver class path then you will have need to add executor class paths to make jar available to executor on worker nodes

Try to use the latest version jar `2.2.8` which shall have the class 
[mongo-spark-connector_2.10:2.2.8](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb.spark/mongo-spark-connector_2.10/2.2.8)

Comment: How should i do it ? Please do assist as i am learning thing in here

Comment: I am running as following, 

spark-submit --class com.LoadData.LoadFromMongoDB --master yarn path/LoadDataSparkModules-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

This is how i execute it

Comment: can u refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37132559/add-jars-to-a-spark-job-spark-submit

Comment: i tried running using the option --driver-class-path , but still the same issue.

Comment: @SamBerchmans Addew few options to add jars. Please check

Comment: :-

I tried the following option , but still facing the same issue. 

`spark-submit --class com.virtualpairprogrammers.LoadFromMongoDB --master yarn /SparkJarPath/DataLoading-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --jar /jarpath/mongo-spark-connector_2.10-1.1.0.jar --driver-class-path=/jarpath/mongo-spark-connector_2.10-1.1.0.jar`

Above option i tried , but still it failed with the same error.

Also Tried the same without Jar and other options, but still the same options.

Comment: Use Mongo Connector 2.2.8 ? Because i am not sure if that MongoConnector is good with 1.6.3 . Let me check the same.

Comment: :- Tried to read the documentation for 2.2.8 , that does not support Spark 1.6.3 version. MongoConnector 1.1.0 is the version which supports 1.6.3

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this issue is,

When i am trying to build using Maven , i am not using Fat Jar build using tools.

Instead of Maven build i tried the following to build a FAT Jar using Eclipse
File -> Export -> Runnable Jar -> Select Class , Jar file Name and choose Option 1 in Library handling. Then click finish.

This is a old type of Jar , but it fixed the issue for me.

Thanks all for the assistance.